# Asus Z87pro: After re-install Win7 blue-screen on starting any game

Tags: motherboard, bsod, gaming

Not my own rig, but that of a colleague.

Asus Z87 Pro based gaming rig. 32 GB RAM, 2x Samsung 840 SSD, Core-I5 (4670), 750W Antec PSU, Geforce GTX 780.
System has been stable running Win7 Ultimate x64 for about a year.
Daily used for gaming and media-center.

Last week he re-installed Win7 from scratch.
There were no hardware changes at all.
As far as I can tell he did everything right regarding drivers.
(Motherboard drivers, Sata, LAN, video, audio in that order. Didn't use drivers from the original CDROMs that came with the hardware. Pulled latest drivers straight from the chipset manufacturers.)

Now as soon as he launches any game the system will BSOD, without logging any reason in eventlog.
After re-installing the GeForce drivers it got slightly better. Sometimes games will start only to fail after 10 minutes or so.

**EDIT** It is NOT a BSOD. The Asus Surge Protection in the Bios causes the system to shut the power off. After that it starts automatically because of the Bios setting "Resume after power-fail".

Before the re-install the system did NEVER do this. The system has been used for a while with 2 of these Geforce GTX-780 cards without issues as well. (So the PSU should be able to handle the load easily with just one of those cards.)

System is stable and running fine with just desktop use and when streaming media to a TV.
Very strange situation.
How best to troubleshoot this issue?

P.S. This might be related, but it doesn't seem likely.
This particular motherboard has an issue with the clock that stalls while the system is running. (You set the time, but after 40-60 minutes the clock just keeps hanging and doesn't update anymore. After a reboot the clock works again.)
My colleague re-installed Win7 in the hope that would fix the clock issue. (If he had Googled he would have found out that it is a known structural problem with some of these Asus boards and he needs to get it replaced under warranty.)
After the re-install the BSOD problems began, the clock is still stalling.
From what I get from Google this clock issue is not known to cause BSOD problems.
**EDIT**  Asus released a Bios fix for this clock issue on 23/6/2014.

I recommended him to get the mb replaced anyway while it is still under warranty because of the clock problems.
(**EDIT** Doesn't seem necessary now.)
But still it is worrisome that something else might be wrong with the rig so he would like to get to the bottom of this.

Any ideas on how to proceed are welcome.

Comment: Use BlueScreenViewer to provide more information on the BSOD.  Try changing the CMOS batter to solve the clock problem.  I am not aware of any ASUS Z87 motherboard problems like you describe though.

Comment: You need to post the BSOD error code (e.g. 0x000000C7) to be able to help pin it down.  Those codes are very specific about the nature of the failure. I don't know why you can't see the code in the system event log, but you can disable automatic restart on system failure so it will stay on the screen long enough to write the code down.

Comment: @Ramhound Google "z87 clock freeze" and you will see plenty of people with the issue. CR2032 has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @WesSayeed Told him to disable the auto-reboot and take note of the code. As I said: Not my own system and I'm not physically in the vicinity.

Comment: Are we talking about the clock or the clock frequency because the results to be frank are by people I don't consider to know what they are talking about.  I have a Z87 chipset, overclocked by 5%, and the first person i found is convinced it should show up.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows system clock freezes. Not the clock-frequency. And on reboot Windows, very helpful, writes the frozen value back to the CMOS clock. His rig isn't overclocked by the way and I know, as you do, that overclocking doesn't affect the real-time and/or Windows system-clock. It's a real pain to filter the noise those "would be" computer experts cause on Google, isn't it.

Comment: @tonny wanted to be sure I understand the claimed z87 problem like I said I have an ASUS system and have not encountered it has anyone tried the CMOS batteries!

Comment: @Ramhound Brandnew CR2032's. Makes no difference. It is a known Asus issue. Some boards are fixable with a Bios update. Others require a replacement. Seems to be related to the exact hardware revision. Only a relatively small number of the early revisions of teh Z87Pro are affected. Asus replaces them if they are still under warranty, but it may take a fair bit of pushing at your local dealer to get the RMA underway. And of course the nuisance of having to rebuild your system.

Comment: upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: @Ramhound Just heard that Asus released a Bios update YESTERDAY (12/6/2014) to fix that clock-freezing issue. Updated the question as well: Cause has become clearer.

Comment: @magicandre1981 There aren't any. New info: Bios based power-surge protection cuts power to the motherboard.

Comment: @Tonny - What motherboard does your friend have exactly. Want to make sure I don't have the same one.

Comment: @Ramhound Just asked him: "Z87-Pro"

Comment: @Tonny - I Should have looked at the title of the question :-)

Comment: have you disabled the pagefile? Windows needs one to write the dumps.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Please read the other comment and the edits: We have established there IS no BSOD happening at all. Power is just cut.

Comment: why do you write "blue screening" if you don't get a BSOD?

Comment: @magicandre1981 As I mentioned it is not my own rig. I didn't see it happen myself, I had to go on the description from my colleague. He initially called it a BSOD with immediate reboot. As in some cases a BSOD (if its bad enough) doesn't write an eventlog entry at all, I couldn't tell either until I he mailed me a photograph of the bios-message that appears after the reboot. That clarified that the Bios PowerSUrge Protection had somehow tripped, without apparent cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this question is 5 years old I figured I best post an answer as it got some interest back in the day and the real cause of this problem finally surfaced.

My colleague got really fed up by the lock-ups and a few months after this question was posted he swapped the Geforce card for the other GTX780 that originally was also in this computer, but that he later had moved to another computer.

As the problem only occurred when the gfx card was under load (gaming) he figured that the problem would move, with the gfx card, to the other computer and that other one was never used for gaming at all.
Strangely enough, after the swap, both computers where stable and remained so for the last 5 years.

Last week he replaced both computers with new systems and gave me the old ones as a donation to the charity I volunteer for.
When I took both computers apart to clean out the dust that had accumulated over the years I discovered the real problem.
The problem gfx card had indeed been the cause of everything all along.

The wire between the PCB and one of the 2 fans on the gfx card was fairly long. Long enough to hang down and touch the motherboard. And the plastic isolation on that wire was damaged, showing a little bit of bare wire.
When the fans of the Geforce card where going fast enough the wire would move a bit in the breeze and cause a short or spark. And that triggered the surge protection.
On the other computer the layout of the motherboard was a bit different with nothing close enough to the wire to cause a problem.

That still didn't explain why the computer had been stable prior to the Win7 re-install, so I asked him earlier today what else he had done when he did that re-install.
It turned out the tower-case had inittialy been used in a vertical position standing under his desk, but he had moved it on top of the desk in a horizontal position to double as a monitor stand. (Him being quite tall hand the non-height-adjustable monitor sitting too low for comfort on his desk.)
In the vertical orientation the wire hang down in free space (left side mounted motherboard) not touching anything, but horizontally the wire sagged enough to lay on and move a bit over the motherboard itself.